# How to get dates for every thursday or other day of week in specific month?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get date of particular day for every week.

Suppose I have a date: `2017-04-13`. It is an April, and 13 April is `Thursday`. I need to get every date in April which is `Thursday`.

How can I do this?

The output should be: `2017-04-06`, `2017-04-13`, `2017-04-20`, `2017-04-27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution:

// Get current calendar and current date
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let now = Date()
    // Get the current date components for year, month, weekday and weekday ordinal
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .weekdayOrdinal, .weekday], from: now)
    // get the range (number of occurrences) of the particular weekday in the month
    let range = calendar.range(of: .weekdayOrdinal, in: .month, for: now)!
    // Loop thru the range, set the components to the appropriate weekday ordinal and get the date
    for ordinal in range.lowerBound..


Be aware that `print` prints dates always in UTC.

**Edit:**

`range(of: .weekdayOrdinal, in: .month` does not work, it returns `1..<6` regardless of the date.

This is a working alternative. It checks if the date exceeds the month bounds

```
// Get current calendar and date for 2017/4/13
let calendar = Calendar.current
let april13Components = DateComponents(year:2017, month:4, day:13)
let april13Date = calendar.date(from: april13Components)!

// Get the current date components for year, month, weekday and weekday ordinal
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .weekdayOrdinal, .weekday], from: april13Date)

// Loop thru the range, set the components to the appropriate weekday ordinal and get the date
for ordinal in 1..<6 { // maximum 5 occurrences
    components.weekdayOrdinal = ordinal
    let date = calendar.date(from: components)!
    if calendar.component(.month, from: date) != components.month! { break }
    print(calendar.date(from: components)!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job. I added some logs to understand some logic behind it.
You can set `dateInit` as you wish, the rest of the code will find all the days that have the same weekday in the same year of the same month.

I printed two versions of date representations (`NSDate` objects and `NSString` objects), for the one having issue with timezones and "it's not the same day" cries.

It uses [`enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar/1413938-enumeratedatesstartingafterdate)

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSString *dateStr = @"2017-04-13";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *dateInit = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"dateInit: %@", dateInit);

NSDateComponents *componentsToMatch = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate:dateInit];

NSDate *startOfMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth) fromDate:dateInit]];
NSLog(@"StartOfTheMonth: %@", startOfMonth);

NSArray *daysToFind = @[@"2017-04-06", @"2017-04-13", @"2017-04-20", @"2017-04-27"]; //According to author
NSLog(@"DaysToFind: %@", daysToFind);

NSMutableArray *allDaysInMonthMatchingWeekDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[calendar enumerateDatesStartingAfterDate:startOfMonth
                       matchingComponents:componentsToMatch
                                  options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly
                               usingBlock:^(NSDate * _Nullable date, BOOL exactMatch, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                                   NSLog(@"DateBlock: %@", date);
                                   [allDaysInMonthMatchingWeekDay addObject:date];
}];

NSLog(@"allDaysInMonthMatchingWeekDay: %@",allDaysInMonthMatchingWeekDay);

for (NSDate *aDate in allDaysInMonthMatchingWeekDay)
{
    NSLog(@"Found: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate]);
}
```

The logs:

```
$>dateInit: 2017-04-12 22:00:00 +0000
$>StartOfTheMonth: 2017-03-31 22:00:00 +0000
$>DaysToFind: (
    "2017-04-06",
    "2017-04-13",
    "2017-04-20",
    "2017-04-27"
)
$>DateBlock: 2017-04-05 22:00:00 +0000
$>DateBlock: 2017-04-12 22:00:00 +0000
$>DateBlock: 2017-04-19 22:00:00 +0000
$>DateBlock: 2017-04-26 22:00:00 +0000
$>allDaysInMonthMatchingWeekDay: (
    "2017-04-05 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2017-04-12 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2017-04-19 22:00:00 +0000",
    "2017-04-26 22:00:00 +0000"
)
$>Found: 2017-04-06
$>Found: 2017-04-13
$>Found: 2017-04-20
$>Found: 2017-04-27
```

Note: For the `componentsToMatch`, I tried to set the Year/Month/WeekDay flags unit, but the enumeration stopped at the first occurence, didn't search long why, I came up with only month and weekday flag to get it work. Maybe some little issue that I missed.

EDIT:
In Swift 3 (it works, but since I'm an Objective-C developer and not a Swift one, it may have issues, like wrapping/unwrapping etc)

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.init(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)

let dateStr = "2017-04-13"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter.init()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let dateInit = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
print("dateInit: \(dateInit)")

let componentsToMatch = calendar?.components([.month,.weekday], from: dateInit)

let startOfMonth = calendar?.date(from: (calendar?.components([.year,.month], from: dateInit))!)
print("StartOfTheMonth:\(startOfMonth)")

calendar?.enumerateDates(startingAfter: startOfMonth!, matching: componentsToMatch!, options: .matchStrictly, using: { (date, extactMatch, stop) in
    print("DateBlock: \(date)")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested in comment. see updated code. updated with week day

```
func getNumberOfDaysInMonth (month : Int , Year : Int, weekday: Int) -> [String]{

    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = Year
    dateComponents.month = month

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents as DateComponents)
    let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date!)

    let numDays:Int = (range?.upperBound)!

    let thuFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var dateArray:[String] = [String]()
    thuFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    for day in 1...numDays {

        dateComponents.day = day

        let date2 = calendar.date(from: dateComponents as DateComponents)
        print(calendar.component(.weekday, from: date2!))
        if calendar.component(.weekday, from: date2!) == weekday
        {

            let dateThu = thuFormatter.string(from: date2!)
            dateArray.append(dateThu)
        }

    }

    return dateArray
}
```

and then call it like

```
let myThu:[String] = getNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: 4, Year: 2017,weekday: 3)
print(myThu)
```

Comment: I'd suggest `let date2 = calendar.date(from: dateComponents as DateComponents); if calendar.component(.weekday, from: date2!) == 5 { numberOfSundays += 1; let dateThu = thuFormatter.string(from: date2!); dateArray.append(dateThu)}` rather than using a `NSDateFormatter` and a String comparison that could change according to languages. And avoid using `NSDateComponents` if it's just for cast it into `DateComponents`, and use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar`, all for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this playground:

```
import UIKit
let dateString = "2017-04-13"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let referenceDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
let calendar = Calendar.current
let firstDayComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: referenceDate)
let monthFirst = calendar.date(from: firstDayComponents)!
let weekDay = calendar.component(.weekday, from: referenceDate)

var oneDay = DateComponents()
oneDay.day = 1

var checkDate = monthFirst
while calendar.component(.month, from: checkDate) == calendar.component(.month, from: referenceDate) {
    if calendar.component(.weekday, from: checkDate) == weekDay {
        let thisDay = dateFormatter.string(from: checkDate)
        print(thisDay)
    }
    checkDate = calendar.date(byAdding: oneDay, to: checkDate)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write an extension for `Calendar` for any given time span and use an enum to name the weekdays

```
enum WeekDay: Int {
    case sunday = 1
    case monday
    case tuesday
    case wednesday
    case thursday
    case friday
    case saturday
}

struct TimeSpan {
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
}

extension Calendar {
    func allOccurrenceOf(day: WeekDay, in timeSpan:TimeSpan) -> [Date] {
        let startDateWeekDay = Int(self.component(.weekday, from: timeSpan.startDate))
        let desiredDay = day.rawValue

        let offset = (desiredDay - startDateWeekDay + 7) % 7
        let firstOccurrence = self.startOfDay(for:self.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day:offset), to: timeSpan.startDate)!)
        guard firstOccurrence.timeIntervalSince1970 < timeSpan.endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 else {
            return []
        }
        var filtered = [firstOccurrence]
        while true {
            let nextDate = self.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: filtered.last!)!
            if nextDate < timeSpan.endDate {
                filtered.append(nextDate)
                break
            }
        }
        return filtered
    }
}
```

Beware that I hacked this could rather fast. I am sure that this can be expressed swiftier. In real production code I would also try to eliminate all `!` from it.

usage:

```
let tuesdays = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.allOccurrenceOf(day: .tuesday, in: TimeSpan(startDate: Date(), endDate: Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month:1), to: Date())!))
```